# error when trying to show values of a vector in angular

Tags: angular, object

I have a vector of a data type (class) defined by me. The error I have is that when I try to print from position 1 onwards, it shows me this: "_this.infurniture [1] is undefined", if I try to print only position 0 if it shows it correctly. I printed the length of the real estate vector and apparently if the variable "real" is being inserted because it shows the correct length, but I do not know what happens. I leave the code below:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HostlistService } from '../servicios/hostlist.service';
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  inmuebles: Inmueble[] = [];
  i = 1;
  url: string = "d782a4ae-733f-b7c4-ed11-5ba553455e04_fot01_c";

  constructor(private hostlistService: HostlistService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cargarJson();


  }

  anteriorInmueble(){
    this.i=this.i-1;
  }

  siguienteInmueble(){
    this.i=this.i+1;
  }

// metodo para cargar el Json recibido de la petición
  cargarJson(){
    var foto1,foto2: string;
    foto1 = "fot0", foto2 = "fot";
    var pos: number;
    this.hostlistService.getInmuebles().subscribe(
        result => {
            if(result.success === true){
                for(const item of result.data) {
                    pos = 0;
                    const inmueble = new Inmueble();
                    inmueble.nombre = item.nomb_prod_c;
                    inmueble.id = item.id;
                    inmueble.estacionamiento = item.estan_c;
                    inmueble.baño = item.banof_c;
                    console.log(inmueble.nombre);
                    (item.fot01_c != "") ? inmueble.fotos[0]="true": inmueble.fotos[0]="false"; pos++;
 
                    this.inmuebles.push(inmueble);
               
                    console.log("----->"+this.inmuebles[0].fotos[0]);
                    console.log("----->"+this.inmuebles[1].fotos[0]);

            }
        }

        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }



    );
  }

}
```

This is the property class:

```js
export class Inmueble {
  nombre: string;
  id: string;
  baño: number;
  estacionamiento: number;
  metro: number;
  precio: number;
  fotos: boolean[];
}
```

note: I realize that if I demystify a 2 object "real2" and print console.log ("----->" + this.infurniture [0] .name); and console.log ("----->" + this.infurniture [1] .name) if they are displayed, so the problem is related to the object or class but I do not know what it could be. I thank in advance who can help me. Thank you

Comment: You are trying to log the `this.inmuebles[1]` in your for cycle - and you are doing it at the 1st cycle too - when your `inmuebles` array contains just 1 element. Move out your logging (console.log) from the for cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized fotos array of inmeuble object. Please do the following -

```
const inmueble = new Inmueble();
inmueble.fotos = [];
inmueble.nombre = item.nomb_prod_c;
inmueble.id = item.id;
inmueble.estacionamiento = item.estan_c;
inmueble.baño = item.banof_c;
console.log(inmueble.nombre);
(item.fot01_c != "") ? inmueble.fotos.push(true): inmueble.fotos.push(false); pos++;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to log the this.inmuebles[1] in your for cycle - and you are doing it at the 1st cycle too - when your inmuebles array contains just 1 element. Move out your logging (console.log) from the for cycle.

I have updated your cargarJson function, moving out the logging:

```
cargarJson(){
    var foto1,foto2: string;
    foto1 = "fot0", foto2 = "fot";
    var pos: number;
    this.hostlistService.getInmuebles().subscribe(
        result => {
            if(result.success === true){
                for(const item of result.data) {
                    pos = 0;
                    const inmueble = new Inmueble();
                    inmueble.nombre = item.nomb_prod_c;
                    inmueble.id = item.id;
                    inmueble.estacionamiento = item.estan_c;
                    inmueble.baño = item.banof_c;
                    console.log(inmueble.nombre);
                    (item.fot01_c != "") ? inmueble.fotos[0]="true": inmueble.fotos[0]="false"; pos++;

                    this.inmuebles.push(inmueble);
                    }
                 console.log("----->"+this.inmuebles[0].fotos[0]);
                 console.log("----->"+this.inmuebles[1].fotos[0]);
            }

        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
  }
```